# How to make correct test project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Good day. I create test project wdho.ru/6Rva
by url
completecsharptutorial.com/mvc-articles/mvc-design-master-page-layout-with-css-html-template.php

But after launching the program, the page display is incorrect and not display image

Best regards

what is wrong ? How to make right ?